# Ruby to C# conversion, assigning to an array indexed by range

Tags: c#, ruby, arrays

I have trouble understanding this since I'm not very familiar with Ruby and I need to convert this code to C#:

```
gifts[(position + 1)..-1] = []
```

gifts is an array, but what does this line do? Does it remove elements from (position + 1) to -1, or marks them as an empty element?

What I'm using is:

```
gifts.RemoveRange(0, position + 1);
```

Comment: If there is something particularly unclear about the documentation of [`Array#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), I'm sure the Ruby team would be [happy to know about it](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/issues/new)!

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I think here it is the odd special-casing of parsing a `Range` end point . . . because e.g. `5..-1` will do different things inside and outside of `[ ]`

Comment: Yeah, array slicing doesn't care about the contents of the range (which in this particular case is just empty), only the start and endpoint. Makes sense, but is non-obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Ruby code `gifts[(position + 1)..-1] = []` removes entries from `position + 1` to `-1` which is "last element of array" in Ruby.

So equivalent code in C# will be

```
gifts.RemoveRange(position + 1, gifts.Count- position - 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

The ruby snippet will remove everything after position:

```
gifts = [1,2,3,4,5];
gifts[2..-1] = [];
gifts; // [1, 2]
```

An equivalent C# snippet (using LINQ) would be:

```
gifts = gifts.Take(position+1).ToList();
```

Or, if you want to modify the list in-place (no LINQ required):

```
gifts.RemoveRange(position + 1, list.Count - position - 1);
```